# Testing React components that are composed of child components

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, react-testing-library

I have a Card components that is split up into bunch of child components.

Example:

```js
export function Card({ title, subtitle, details }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <CardHeader title={title} sutitle={subtitle} />
      <CardDetails detailOne={details.one} detailTwo={details.two} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I can see three ways of testing this and I don't know which one would be the best.

What I am thinking of is to test only if the child components render inside the `Card` tests using test ids, like so:

```js
const testDetails = {
  detailOne: '1',
  detailTwo: '2',
};

describe('Card', () => {
  it('should render header', () => {
    render(<Card title="test" subtitle="testsubtitle" details={testDetails} />);
    expect(screen.getByTestId('card-header')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  it('should render details', () => {
    render(<Card title="test" subtitle="testsubtitle" details={testDetails} />);
    expect(screen.getByTestId('card-details')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

And check the rendered props inside the children tests, f.ex.:

```js
describe('CardHeader', () => {
  it('should render correct title and subtitle', () => {
    const testTitle = 'testTitle';
    const testSubtitle = 'testSubtitle';

    render(<CardHeader title={testTitle} subtitle={testSubtitle} />);
    expect(screen.getByRole('heading', testTitle)).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText(testSubtitle)).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

The second way would be to just test if the correct props are rendered in the parent `Card` component and don't test the child components at all.

And the third one is to test correct props for both `Card` and the child components, but it seems like unnecessary test duplication.

Which one would you say is the correct way?